# Running servlet from faces-config

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

It will be hard to explain..
So, in a.jsp I have something like this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                    <td><input type="text" name="imgName" value="" size="7"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="imgDesc" value="" size="30"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <x:upload target="/upload/#{loginBean.user.login}/#{loginBean.user.filesUploaded}_image.jpg"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>                            
                        <h:commandButton value="Send" action="submit"/>
                    </td>
                    </h:form>
```

Now, pressing "Send" button will run filter, because (as I assume) that filter runs for every Faces Servlet (so for every jsp?). My web.xml file:

```
    <filter>
      <filter-name>Upload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>DomainModels.Adds.UploadFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sizeThreshold</param-name>
         <param-value>1024</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Upload Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
```

How can I force running servlet after filtering? I've read somewhere that I have to write simple `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>`. Ok, so I've changed "action" attribute to "TestServlet.do", added this:

```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>DomainModels.Adds.AddImage</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/TestServlet.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

but still my TestServlet doesn't work..
I was trying to add into faces-config.xml this:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/upload/a.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>submit</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/TestServlet.do</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

but it gives no result..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<h:form>` by `<form>` so that you can utilize the `action` attribute.

Alternatively, don't use a servlet, but just use a managed bean action the JSF way. You only need to implement `decode()` of that homegrown `x:upload` component accordingly that it puts the uploaded file which is collected by the filter as a bean property. Or if that's too much work, just reuse an existing JSF file upload component, like Tomahawk's `t:inputFileUpload`. How to use it can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html).

Comment: So if I want to do something, I just have to place it in decode() method? I do have something like this in my code, and (if I'm understanding it correctly) it is used to save uploaded file from filter. But will I be able to get values from beans?